# How can I open a list of URLs in new tabs with Firefox through a Batch File (four at a time)?

Tags: firefox, batch-file, command-line, cmd, command-prompt

So I have a list of URLs in a text file that I'm trying to open with Firefox in new tabs through a Batch File (.bat). The program needs to open the **first four** tabs and then prompt the user if they want to open the **next four** tabs.

**Text File (*urls.txt*):**

```
http://www.google.com/
http://www.facebook.com/
http://www.youtube.com/
http://www.yahoo.com/
http://www.wikipedia.org/
http://www.amazon.com/
http://www.twitter.com/
http://www.linkedin.com/
http://www.live.com/
http://www.ebay.com/
http://www.blogspot.com/
http://www.bing.com/
```

**My Not-So-Successful Attempt:**

```
set counter=0
set /p="start firefox " <nul > newcommand.txt
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (urls.txt) do (
    if counter < 5 (
        set /p="%%a " <nul >> newcommand.txt
        set /a counter=counter+1
    ) else (
        goto round2
    )
)

for /f "delims=" %%b in (newcommand.txt) do %%b
del newcommand.txt

:round2
echo.
echo Press Enter to exit the program...
pause > nul
```

My program crashes, and I think it might have something to do with my for loop.

Does anybody have knowledge that could help me accomplish this task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for new tab open just do `firefox.exe fb.com stackoverflow.com` 
now get all site from your site file and solve your problem

```
for /f %a in (pathof.txt) do pathoffirefox.exe %g
```

reference :
[for](http://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html)